# Using a 5V Optical Mouse USB Cable to Power a toy requiring 4 Size D batteries

Tags: batteries, usb

I have a baby swing which requires 4 Size D batteries to get power. Here's a picture of such a thing - a human baby goes inside.

[image: A picture of a baby swing]

Googling the information on Size D batteries, I found that 4 Size D batteries equals

```
1.5 V * 4 = 6V
```

I want to power this toy using an old optical mouse USB cable.

The specification on the mouse says 5V and 100mA.

Questions:

1) Can I use this cable to power my toy ?

2) Is this correct: Red Wire in the mouse cable connects to Positive Node of the toy and Black Wire in the mouse cable connects to Negative Node of the toy ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The red is VCC and Black is ground, the other two is data.

Comment: @Butzke: Will it work ? 5V USB Cable with a 6V Device (the device requiring 4 D Size Batteries) ?

Comment: A device that requires D cells is likely to require much more than 100ma. It won't work, even ignoring the 1V difference.

Comment: @DoxyLover: Will an old phone charger work ?

Comment: If you use a USB charger rated for 2A, it will probably work, although it might be a little bit slow. I wouldn't do it, however, because of electrical safety. If it plugs into the wall, I would not plug it into a toy my child was playing with (Unless it is a quality USB "charger" specifically intended for kids toys.)

Comment: Your true unknown is how much current does the device draw from the 6V source made from 4 D cells? It could be up to 10A.

Comment: @DanD.: Yes.. :(  and I don't know how to find that out...

Answer (score 1):

I would have a bit of a reservation about powering a baby swing from a random wall-wart supply. Normally, of course, such supplies work fine, and the baby isn't supposed to touch other grounded surfaces, but the swing wasn't really designed for it.

There are two areas of concern:

1. Electrical Safety

   If your supply's isolation fails, you might have a dangerous situation as the baby is normally strapped into the swing. A grounded adult touching such a swing might then electrocute themselves and/or the baby.
2. Physical Safety

   The supply cord becomes a nice strangulation hazard. Make sure that it's properly zip-tied to the supporting structure and routed out of reach of the baby!

When it comes to devices that are in forced, constant contact with the body, such as in a baby swing, I'd not use a random supply, but buy a medical grade power supply, such as [this one](http://www.newark.com/xp-power/vep15us05/adaptor-ac-dc-medical-5v-2a/dp/04R9687). It's only $15 at this time + shipping.

Before you spend on such a supply, it'd be worthwhile to calculate how much money you're going to save in batteries over the life of the device. I'd also not randomly switch over to rechargeable batteries: they can be a real fire hazard in devices not designed (read: at least fused) to accommodate them.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I don't recommend this.  You should use bigger wire.

---

The voltage will be fine; that's an insulation rating, which is really hard to make thin enough to be a problem at any low voltage without chafing through.

If you're completely re-purposing the cable with no connection to any of its original stuff, then the color code technically doesn't matter.  Just make sure that the right connections get made from one end to the other.  However, it's still good to follow a convention like Butzke mentioned.

I'd be more concerned about the current.  A D-size battery is probably capable of several amps continuous, and the cable is only designed for 100mA.  That rating is for the wire size.  It'll probably work though...for a while.  Then you might have hot wires oozing out the side of the cable.

Comment: Can I use any wire with a power plug which goes directly on the wall power input ? e.g. from a phone charger ? I am in the US.

Comment: I am trying to power a baby swing which requires 4 D size batteries.

Comment: OOHH!!!  You're powering this from the wall!  I thought you were tethering it to a remote battery pack.  Please edit the question for future readers.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend a serious 5-6V power supply.  If it doesn't come with its own DC wiring, put some speaker wire on it.

Comment: I am open to suggestions. How should I power this ? I want to convert the swing requiring 4 D size batteries to consume power from the wall. The wires I have are old cell phone charger, which directly plugs to the wall and an old optical mouse with a USB cable.

Comment: I don't think either one of those will work.  Too much current, even for the phone charger.  If you have an old desktop computer, the red/black wires from its power supply will give you 5V and more current than you'd know what to do with.  Otherwise, go shopping for maybe 5-6V, 5A or better.

Comment: http://kellyabobbyc.blogspot.com/2012/08/convert-your-baby-swing-from-battery.html   : This link does it using phone charger...

Comment: Hmm...well, one thing that might save you here is the actual current requirement.  It could be that it uses D batteries for their storage capacity, not for high power.  If that's the case, then a phone charger and mouse cord might work.  But I'm not going to recommend it without knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with using a cell phone charger if you plan on stripping a USB cable. A lot of devices will run until each battery drops to 1v (See EEVBlog https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iEshd6izgk), and a 5v phone charger can produce an output voltage from 4.75v to 5.25v, which should be more than enough to operate the toy. You'll just want to make sure the current rating of the charger is high enough for the toy.

You could also try a few different chargers if they have the USB connection on them, if under 5v won't work.

Comment: There is no current rating given on the device. Its a Baby Swing FYI if it helps in guiding me.

Comment: @Vicky: I've read that some can draw up to 800mA, so I'd say just go with a phone charger that is rated at an amp or so. Here's a link to someone using a phone charger to power their baby swing [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Convert-a-Baby-Swing-from-Batteries-to-AC-wall-P/?ALLSTEPS)